# Compare String with Spring Security tag using Freemarker

Tags: spring, spring-security, freemarker

How can I achieve the following with Freemarker and Spring Security taglibs?

```
<#if "[]" == <@security.authentication property='principal.userAccount.administratedVendors'/> >
    <a href="/my-accounts">My Accounts</a>
</#if>
```

Currently, the above doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of here problem is that `security.authentication` shouldn't be a FreeMarker directive, but a FreeMarker function or method. Directives don't have a return value (therefore you can't use them in place of an expression, like you did). Directives can print to the output (among others), but that's just a "side effect", not a return value. FreeMarker functions/methods have a return value. But if the Spring integration doesn't provide the same call as function/method (check that), then the best you can do is this ugly workaround:

```
<#assign capturedOutput><@security.authentication property='principal.userAccount.administratedVendors'/></#assign>
<#if capturedOutput == '[]'>
  <a href="/my-accounts">My Accounts</a>
</#if>
```

It's bit fragile in theory, as (I guess) `principal.userAccount` just prints the `toString()` of the property value object. While for most `List` implementations that will return `"[]"` for an empty list,, it's not guaranteed by the Java API.